# Here Rest Api Altitude Road

Tags: rest, here-api

For my PhD thesis I need the altitudes of a driven route from the surface of the road.
Is this possible with the HERE REST API?

Thanks in advance,

Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure if the Platform Data Extension API might be useful for the use case. It has many layers and attributes, and the layer ROAD_GEOM_FCn has an attribute Z Level which is similar to what you are looking for

Documentation 
https://developer.here.com/platform-extensions/documentation/platform-data/topics/overview.html

http://tcs.ext.here.com/pde/layer?region=WEU&release=2015Q4&url_root=pde.cit.api.here.com&layer=ROAD_GEOM_FC1